# Unconfirmed Block Chain transaction

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions

On 4-Jan 2017, I have made a BTC payment and now,it's been more than 16+hours to my unconfirmed transaction of 0.1313828 BTC through blockchain wallet.

Please help either to revert back this amount in my blockchain wallet or send it to the same address.

URL: https://blockchain.info/tx/5f3088954a3960132bd52438d4b7124bab50d2776c7ce9bdf158d37dc53d8786

Query:
Will it revert back automatically?
Do I need to do something to pull or push it further? Please suggest

I really appreciate if someone helps me as I read certain blogs this is due to low commission fees and nobody picking it during BTC mining.

Thanks

Comment: Two of your inputs are unconfirmed, thus your transaction has been slow to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could be, that your Transaction is not confirmed.
Pls check unconfirmed Transactions here:

https://blockchain.info/de/unconfirmed-transactions

~ 16000 unconfirmed Transactions.

Until they are packed in Blocks it could take some hours - days.
Depends on how large the transactions are it could take some days, because Blocks have a maximum size of 1 KB.

Sometimes there are just ~700 transactions mined per Block and it reaches 1 KB, sometimes there are > 2500 Transactions put in one block.

I think push will not be a solution because it was already broadcasted to Network.

So be patient it will be confirmed soon :)

Regards